# Application will automatically launch after installation on device-iPhone

Tags: iphone, installation, uiapplicationdelegate, uiwindow

I have make an application. In this application client need that when user download form app store then after download it will install on Device.

After installation application will launch automatically.

I mean to say that when we install any application on device then it will show only application's icon. That will not launch application automatically. That needs user interaction once to icon.

So i want to implement that when application's installation process finish then application will launch automatically without any single user interaction.

How apply this functionality in application?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: if you haven't seen any apps, out of the hundreds of thousands of them, that does this, it is very unlikely that it is possible to achieve such goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tweak iOS code to achieve this. But Apple wont accept trespassing and will reject your app. **In short, you dont have control over this.**

Comment: I don't need any solution for jail-broken devices. If have any other solution except jaibreak then i respect your solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience i think you cant do this.